# WPF XAML Binding in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

How can i bind a listbox for exemple to a method which is in another project like this :

Project1(BDD)
Class1
Project2(GUI)
class2

I want to bind a listbox itemSource in the second project(GUI), with a class created in my first project(BDD).

Comment: Is the source in the second project a static class? Have you tried applying class2 as the DataContext of the control/window?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i bind a listbox for exemple to a method which is in another project?

Put simply, we don't do that in WPF. Instead, you should add a reference to the other project, add a `using` declaration and then instantiate an object from that class. Then (assuming that your method returns a collection of some sort) you should set the output of the method to a collection property that you then data bind to the `ItemsSource` property.

Here's a very basic example:

```
private ObservableCollection<int> numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers
{
    get { return numbers; }
    set { numbers = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Numbers"); }
}
```

...

```
Numbers = new YourClassFromOtherProject().GetData();
```

...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" ... />
```